# Можно ли употреблять словосочетания "ситуация вокруг", "скандал вокруг"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, лексическая-сочетаемость

"Ситуация вокруг", "скандал вокруг" — можно ли употреблять эти словосочетания? Мне они кажутся безграмотными.

Comment: Допустим, "ситуация вокруг Афганистана остается напряженной". Как бы вы сказали по-другому?

Comment: Возможно, это новая языковая норма. Для меня выражение "ситуация вокруг" в принципе неприемлемо - режет слух. Нужно перефразировать все предложение, например, "политическая ситуация, сложившаяся в результате..." и т.д.

Comment: "В результате" чего? Чувствуете, как длинно будет? Да и не новая это норма, я такое слышал лет тридцать-сорок назад.

Comment: Иногда лучше длинно, чем коряво.

Comment: Я понимаю, что это дело вкуса. Хотелось бы услышать мнение профессиональных лингвистов.

Comment: То, что выражения эти широко употребляются, - этого для вас недостаточно? Лингвисты ведь не создают языков - они их только изучают. И на процессы, происходящие в языке, не влияют - только фиксируют.

Впрочем, ждите. )

Comment: Это верно. Но вовсе не значит что нужно соглашаться с неграмотностью, превращающейся в норму.

Comment: Тут вот какая штука. Неграмотность, превратившаяся в норму, -- это уже не неграмотность. Это норма. И ничего с этим не поделать. Вот, например, сейчас неграмотно говорить "звОнит", а лет через тридцать будет грамотно. Все к этому идет.

Comment: Да, к сожалению

Comment: Почему "к сожалению"? Язык ведь не нечто застывшее в одной раз навсегда утвердившейся "норме", он меняется.

Comment: Да. И это значит, что тюремный жаргон может стать нормой. Поэтому "к сожалению"

Comment: А где вы здесь увидели "тюремный жаргон"?

Я бы советовал вам почитать популярную книжку известного лингвиста М.Кронгауза "Русский язык на грани нервного срыва". Ее легко можно найти в сети.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: Все что мне хотелось узнать, это мнение стилистов о допустимости таких выражений в академических текстах, не в публицистике. Тюремный жаргон был упомянут к слову, и Вы это знаете.

Answer (score 4):

В словаре на Грамоте.ру указано такое значение:

**ВОКРУГ.** I. нареч. Кругом, во все стороны. Осмотреться в. Обойти здание в. Ни одной деревни в. **II. предлог.** кого-чего. 1. Кругом, около. Сесть в. стола. В. дома забор. Уложить косу в. головы. Путешествие в. света. **2. По поводу кого-, чего-л. Спор разгорелся в. политики.**

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=вокруг&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3&all=x)

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.
Публикуется в авторской редакции 2014 года.

Примеры взяты из Нацкорпуса:

Какова сейчас **ситуация вокруг**  военных баз в Грузии? В ту пору и разгорелся **скандал вокруг** этой сделки.

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%E8%F2%F3%E0%F6%E8%FF+%E2%EE%EA%F0%F3%E3

Выражение активно  применяется в публицистических текстах.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте ссылку ни источник. Некоторым словарям лучше не доверятью

Comment: И да, публицисты используют, но это не значит что их стиль - вершина литературного вкуса.

Comment: Так в публицистике и не нужны вершины стилистики. Не нужно в жемчуге искать золото. Или в жареной картошке искать вкус "наполеона".

Comment: Никто с этим не спорит, но тем хуже для публицистики. Это все равно что сказать что в уличных кафе вполне уместна некачественная еда. Да, она там бывает, но это не должно восприниматься нормальным.

Comment: @Юля словарям приходится доверять, другое дело, что они часто приводят взаимоисключающие рекомендации. Кузнецов действительно иногда выступает с весьма оригинальными мнениями, но в вопросах толкования значений он специалист, тут уж ничего не попишешь. А уж спорить о вкусах публицистов просто не стоит. лучше просто принимать к сведению наметившуюся тенденцию.  Рано или поздно она будет или отвергнута, или узаконена. В нашем случае всего вероятнее второе. Кузнецов, собственно, уже и узаконил..

Comment: @Юля, а ваша разговорная речь совсем не отличается от вашей же письменной? Или "тем хуже для разговорной"? Это так, к примеру.

Comment: Да, отличается, но я стараюсь говорить грамотно

Answer (score 2):

Из комментария Юли в этой теме:

> Пожалуйста, дайте ссылку на источник. Некоторым словарям лучше не
>   доверять.

Словарю Ожегова доверяете?

Из его "Словаря русского языка" **1953** года:

**ВОКРУГ** <…> 2. *перен., предлог с род. п.* **По поводу чего-н.** *Споры вокруг сложного вопроса.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сравните: "споры вокруг Афганистана" и "споры вокруг ситуации в Афганистане" - первое явно является стилистическим ухудшением второго. К тому же, первое предполагает что это споры *физически* расположены в пространстве вокруг Афганистана.

Answer (score 1):

В толковом словаре [**Ожегова**](https://file:///C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/TempState/Downloads/Vokrug-3851%20(1).html):
**Вокруг**
1. *нареч.* В окружности, по окрестностям, кругом кого-чего-нибудь.
Оглядеться вокруг. ***Вокруг ни души. Вокруг друзья.***

Теоретически ничто вам не мешает переставить слова местами:
вокруг ни души = ни души вокруг;
вокруг друзья = друзья вокруг.

Абстрактно, если я вас правильно поняла (вы не указываете контекста):

– И что же тебя так угнетает?
– Ситуация вокруг.

Comment: А как Вам такоеЖ– И что же тебя так угнетает?

Comment: А как Вам такое: – И что же тебя так угнетает? – Ситуация вокруг Афганистана... Совсем не то же самое, правда? Звучит коряво.

Answer (score 1):

Юля, профессиональных лингвистов тут не так много, да и не все они узкие специалисты именно в вопросе правильной речи. Позвольте уж и дилетантам поучаствовать.

Такие сочетания несут легкий оттенок разговорности, но в целом вполне нормативны. Это и подтверждают словари.

Насколько могу судить, это сравнительно новое образование, в русском языке не было такого предлога, который бы сочетал в себе сразу несколько значений "по поводу", "насчет", "вызванный чем?", "связанный с чем?" и прочее.

В английском все и еще много чего передается простым словом "about". Очень похоже, что наше "вокруг [ситуации]" является попыткой прямого перевода английского слова. Ничего страшного в том нет, заполнение языковой ниши вполне оправдано.

Answer (score 0):

Если человек находится в центре скандала,  значит и скандал может находиться (нарастать) вокруг него.  Если же он оказался в определённой ситуации, то вполне логично и то, что ситуация складывается (развивается) вокруг него.

Comment: находиться, нарастать

Comment: ситуация развивается на основе чего-то, а не вокруг

Comment: Если я нахожусь в сложной ситуации, в затруднительно положении, вокруг меня сложились определённые обстоятельства...  Но не указываю причину развития этой ситуации

Comment: Ситуация сложилась не вокруг Вас, а в связи с чем-то. То же с обстоятельствами - они не вокруг Вас, у Вас. Это аберрация восприятия - если часто слышать неправильное словоупотребление, оно становится привычным.

Comment: Юлия, @Niemand, "ситуация вокруг проблемы" — это образец образного мышления, вот и все,  "ситуация вокруг Афганистана" можно понять двояко: в переносном смысле и в прямом (в соседних странах).